# Integración con pantallas Login de Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, login, windows10

Quería hacer una dll en C# para poder mostrar un mensaje en la pantalla de cambio de contraseña propia de Windows 10 para indicarle al usuario las políticas de contraseña que debe cumplir, pero sin interferir en la validación de la misma (ya que esto lo gestiona un tercero).

He estado viendo en la MSDN referencias a Windows Hello Login pero yo creo que es para hacer un Login independiente al que ya ofrece W10:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport-login

Y WinLogon también ofrece la posibilidad de integrarse con el login de W10 pero para gestionar tú mismo la autenticación, no para intervenir en la interfaz del usuario, que es lo único que busco...

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-and-credential-providers

A ver si alguno ha hecho algo parecido alguna vez,

Gracias de antemano.
Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: por lo regular las contraseñas te las pide que las cambies cada 2 meses en mi caso, y te llega un mensaje 10 dias antes de que caduque el password, eso es una politica del Active DIrectory creo que se lo deberias de pedir al que administra el AD que haga eso.